Change some underscores by numeric rule
I'd a vector:
myvec <- c("CERRO_DO_OURO_003F","AQUA_002","TAMOIOS_DELTA_001","URURTUBA_04C") 

I'd like to change the underscore by a rule, for example, if the underscore is followed by a number, I'd like to not remove it like this:
myvecnew
[1] "CERRODOOURO_003F" "AQUA_002" "TAMOIOSDELTA_001" "URURTUBA_04C"

I tried to use gsub, but I'm not able to do it. Could you help me?

(a) your sample input isn't valid. (Needs more quotes). Please run it before posting it to make sure it works. (b) What did you try with gsub? Try searching for "regex negative lookahead", that would be one way to solve this problem.

Try gsub("_(\\D)", "\\1", myvec)
